# Using multiple forms on a page in Django

Tags: django-views

How do I use more than one form per page in Django?

Comment: Please provide more information, otherwise we cannot help you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Proper way to handle multiple forms on one page in Django](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395807/proper-way-to-handle-multiple-forms-on-one-page-in-django)

Answer (score 17):

Please see the following previously asked (and answered) questions:

[Django: multiple models in one template using forms](https://stackoverflow.com/q/569468/445210)

and

[Proper way to handle multiple forms on one page in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1395807/445210).

Depending on what you're really asking, this is my favorite way to handle different models on the same page:

```
if request.POST():
    a_valid = formA.is_valid()
    b_valid = formB.is_valid()
    c_valid = formC.is_valid()
    # we do this since 'and' short circuits and we want to check to whole page for form errors
    if a_valid and b_valid and c_valid:
        a = formA.save()
        b = formB.save(commit=False)
        c = formC.save(commit=False)
        b.foreignkeytoA = a
        b.save()
        c.foreignkeytoB = b
        c.save()
```

Comment: thank you for your explanation. In my case, I have two models (Parent & child) and rendering both forms in a single template. When I'm submitting the form, parent.is_valid() is returning true but child.is_valid() is false and the error says "This field can not be empty" where the "This field" is my foreign key model field in child Model

Answer (score 5):

Judging by the date of your questions I am going to assume you are using class based views, below is copied from my other answer here: [Proper way to handle multiple forms on one page in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395807/proper-way-to-handle-multiple-forms-on-one-page-in-django/17303425#17303425)

```
class NegotiationGroupMultifacetedView(TemplateView):
    ### TemplateResponseMixin
    template_name = 'offers/offer_detail.html'

    ### ContextMixin 
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        """ Adds extra content to our template """
        context = super(NegotiationGroupDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        ...

        context['negotiation_bid_form'] = NegotiationBidForm(
            prefix='NegotiationBidForm', 
            ...
            # Multiple 'submit' button paths should be handled in form's .save()/clean()
            data = self.request.POST if bool(set(['NegotiationBidForm-submit-counter-bid',
                                              'NegotiationBidForm-submit-approve-bid',
                                              'NegotiationBidForm-submit-decline-further-bids']).intersection(
                                                    self.request.POST)) else None,
            )
        context['offer_attachment_form'] = NegotiationAttachmentForm(
            prefix='NegotiationAttachment', 
            ...
            data = self.request.POST if 'NegotiationAttachment-submit' in self.request.POST else None,
            files = self.request.FILES if 'NegotiationAttachment-submit' in self.request.POST else None
            )
        context['offer_contact_form'] = NegotiationContactForm()
        return context

    ### NegotiationGroupDetailView 
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = self.get_context_data(**kwargs)

        if context['negotiation_bid_form'].is_valid():
            instance = context['negotiation_bid_form'].save()
            messages.success(request, 'Your offer bid #{0} has been submitted.'.format(instance.pk))
        elif context['offer_attachment_form'].is_valid():
            instance = context['offer_attachment_form'].save()
            messages.success(request, 'Your offer attachment #{0} has been submitted.'.format(instance.pk))
                # advise of any errors

        else 
            messages.error('Error(s) encountered during form processing, please review below and re-submit')

        return self.render_to_response(context)
```

The html template is to the following effect:

```
...

<form id='offer_negotiation_form' class="content-form" action='./' enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ negotiation_bid_form.as_p }}
    ...
    <input type="submit" name="{{ negotiation_bid_form.prefix }}-submit-counter-bid" 
    title="Submit a counter bid"
    value="Counter Bid" />
</form>

...

<form id='offer-attachment-form' class="content-form" action='./' enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ offer_attachment_form.as_p }}

    <input name="{{ offer_attachment_form.prefix }}-submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

...
```

Comment: This: `data = self.request.POST if 'NegotiationAttachment-submit' in self.request.POST else None`!!!!

Comment: @zeraien ? - can you clarify

Comment: When having multiple forms on the same page, adding a key/value to the submit button was what allowed me to differentiate the different forms in the view processing code. So in my case I created a little method that I call for each form...

`def _get_post(request, prefix): return request.POST if '%s-submit' % prefix in request.POST else None`
and each form just calls that to get the POST data:
`password_form = PasswordChangeForm(user=request.user, data=_get_post(request, 'password'), prefix='password')`

That line gave me the inspiration to do that ;-)