# Django update/create architecture

Tags: django, architecture

I have worked out a way for myself how to create and update my Django models. But I am wondering if this is the correct way. Let's say we have two models A and B, where one A can have many B's.

Here B has two user inputs b1, b2 and "b3" is defined as: b3 = b1 + b2

Here A also has two user input fields a1, a2 and "a3" is defined as: 
a3 = a1 + a2 + b[0].b3 + b[1].b3 + ... + b[N].b3

Here A depends on the zero or more B's. If one of the B's changes, than A will need to recalculate it's a3 field.

The A and B models are therefore defined as:

```
class A(models.Model):
    a1      = models.FloatField(default=0)
    a2      = models.FloatField(default=0)
    a3      = models.FloatField(default=0)

    @classmethod
    def create( cls, a1, a2):
        a   = cls(a1  = a1, a2  = a2)
        return a

    def set_a(self, a):
        a.a3 = a.a1 + a.a2

        bs = B.objects.filter(a=a)
        for b in bs:
            a.a3 += b.b3
        a.save()
        return a

class B(models.Model):
    a       = models.ForeignKey('a.A', related_name='bs', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    b1      = models.FloatField(default=0)
    b2      = models.FloatField(default=0)
    b3      = models.FloatField(default=0)

    @classmethod
    def create( cls, a, b1, b2):
        b   = cls(  a = a, b1  = b1, b2  = b2)
        return b

    def set_b(self, b):
        b.b3 = b.b1 + b.b2
        b.save()
        b.a.set_a(b.a)
        return b
```

The create and update views for the "a" app are:

```
class ACreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = A
    template_name = 'a/create.html'
    form_class = AForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        a = A.create(   a1      = form.cleaned_data['a1'],
                        a2      = form.cleaned_data['a2'])
        a = a.set_a(a)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('a:detail', args=(a.id,)))


class AUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = A
    template_name = 'a/detail-update.html'
    form_class = AForm

    def get_object(self):
        return get_object_or_404(A, pk=self.kwargs['pk_a'])

    def form_valid(self, form):
        a = self.get_object()
        a.a1        = form.cleaned_data['a1']
        a.a2        = form.cleaned_data['a2']
        a = a.set_a(a)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('a:detail', args=(a.id,)))
```

The question is now is this the correct way? Is it correct to have the save() command in the set_a(a) functions? It seems to work for this very simple example but if the models increase so the complexity will increase and this method is perhaps no longer viable...

Comment: If it works, it’s good enough for me. You should write tests for it to make sure that it will still work later.

Answer (score 0):

Another perhaps more elegant way is to define a3 and b3 as properties and not store them in the database. This way a3 and b3 are immediately calculated when needed. An update in the b1 and b2 fields of the B model will immediately result in a new updated value of the a3 property.

Of course the disadvantage is that we cannot (easily) query the database for a3 and b3 since they are not stored in the database.

The A model is than defined as:

```
from django.db import models
from b.models import B

class A(models.Model):
    a_name  = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    a1      = models.FloatField(default=0)
    a2      = models.FloatField(default=0)

    @classmethod
    def create( cls, a_name, a1, a2):
        a   = cls(  a_name = a_name, a1  = a1, a2  = a2)
        b1 = B.create(a = a, b_name = "auto_created_b1", b1 = 999, b2=0)
        return a

    @property
    def a3(self):
        a3 = self.a1 + self.a2
        bs = B.objects.filter(a=self)
        for b in bs:
            a3 += b.b3
        return a3

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('a:detail', kwargs={'pk_a':self.id })
```

The update and create views for the A model is:

```
class ACreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = A
    template_name = 'a/create.html'
    form_class = AForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        a = A.create(   a_name  = form.cleaned_data['a_name'],
                        a1      = form.cleaned_data['a1'],
                        a2      = form.cleaned_data['a2'])
        a.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('a:detail', args=(a.id,)))

class AUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = A
    template_name = 'a/detail-update.html'
    form_class = AForm

    def get_object(self):
        return get_object_or_404(A, pk=self.kwargs['pk_a'])

    def form_valid(self, form):
        a = self.get_object()
        a.a_name    = form.cleaned_data['a_name']
        a.a1        = form.cleaned_data['a1']
        a.a2        = form.cleaned_data['a2']
        a.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('a:detail', args=(a.id,)))
```