# Create and UpdateView with foreign key related model in Django CBV

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-class-based-views

I got 1 app "portfolio" with 2 models, the 2nd one has a FK with first and I need (create and update) view of that. I have the complete CRUD for the first model but I no have idea to get the same result with fk model. I'm looking for a create and update view with both. But I can't get access for proyects in a album form, so in that way for choosing the FK from projects to get related album to one of all projects created

***models.py***

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField

# Create your models here.

class Project(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE, default=1)
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name='Nombre del proyecto', max_length=200)
    client = models.CharField(verbose_name='Nombre del cliente', max_length=200)
    description = RichTextField(verbose_name='Descripción')
    start = models.DateField(verbose_name='Fecha de Inicio', null=True, blank=True)
    ending = models.DateField(verbose_name='Fecha de Finalización', null=True, blank=True)
    order = models.SmallIntegerField(verbose_name="Orden", default=0)
    created = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='Fecha de creación', auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='Fecha de modificación', auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Proyecto'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Proyectos'
        ordering = ['-start', 'order']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Album(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(verbose_name='Título de la imagen', max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(verbose_name='Imagen', upload_to='portfolio')
    created = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='Fecha de creación', auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='Fecha de modificación', auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Imagen en el album'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Imágenes en el album'
        ordering = ['created']

        def __str__(self):
            return self.title
```

***views.py***

```
@method_decorator(staff_member_required(login_url='login'), name='dispatch')
class ProjectCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Project
    template_name = "core/project_create_form.html"
    form_class = ProjectCreateForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')

@method_decorator(staff_member_required(login_url='login'), name='dispatch')
class ProjectUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = Project
    template_name = "core/project_update_form.html"
    form_class = ProjectUpdateForm


@method_decorator(staff_member_required(login_url='login'), name='dispatch')
class ProjectDeleteView(DeleteView):
    model = Project
    template_name = "core/project_delete_form.html"
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')
```

***forms.py***

```
class ProjectCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):

    template_name = 'core/project_create_form.html'

    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = [
            'name',
            'client',
            'description',
            'start',
            'ending',
            'order',
            ]

        widgets = {

            'name':forms.TextInput(
                attrs={
                    'class':'form-control'}),

            'client':forms.TextInput(
                attrs={
                    'class':'form-control'}),

            'description':forms.Textarea(
                attrs={
                    'class':'form-control'}),

            'start':forms.DateInput(
                attrs={
                    'class':'form-control'}),

            'ending':forms.DateInput(
                attrs={
                    'class':'form-control'}),

            'order':forms.NumberInput(
                attrs={
                    'class':'form-control'}),
        }


class ProjectUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):

    template_name = 'core/project_update_form.html'

    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = [
            'name',
            'client',
            'description',
            'start',
            'ending',
            'order',
            ]

        widgets = {

            'name':forms.TextInput(
                attrs={
                    'class':'form-control'}),

            'client':forms.TextInput(
                attrs={
                    'class':'form-control'}),

            'description':forms.Textarea(
                attrs={
                    'class':'form-control'}),

            'start':forms.DateInput(
                attrs={
                    'class':'form-control'}),

            'ending':forms.DateInput(
                attrs={
                    'class':'form-control'}),

            'order':forms.NumberInput(
                attrs={
                    'class':'form-control'}),
        }
```

Comment: So you’re looking to have both project and album forms on the same page?

Comment: Yes, something like this: [Example](https://imgur.com/a/gsNccJh)

Comment: I might not get you all the way there, but here are some links that I saved to help me. [inlineformsets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50771962/two-models-fields-in-one-form-in-django-2-0) and [multiple forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5857363/using-multiple-forms-on-a-page-in-django).

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this library but it might solve your problem, a common problem in Django is how to have a view, especially a class-based view that can display and process multiple forms at once.
https://github.com/kennethlove/django-shapeshifter