# Html code for showing multiple forms on one page

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

Below is the view

```
def TestPageView(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        contactform = ContactForm(request.POST,prefix="contact")
        subscriptionform = SubscriptionForm(request.POST,prefix="subscription")
        suggestionform  = SuggestionForm(request.POST,prefix="suggestion")
        globalmessageform = GlobalMessageForm(request.POST,prefix="globalmessage")

        if contactform.is_valid() and subscriptionform.is_valid() and suggestionform.is_valid() and globalmessageform.is_valid():
            contact = contactform.save()
            subscription = subscriptionform.save()
            suggestion = suggestionform.save()
            globalmessage = globalmessageform.save()

        else:
            print(form.errors)
    else:
        contactform = ContactForm(prefix="contact")
        subscriptionform = SubscriptionForm(prefix="subscription")
        suggestionform  = SuggestionForm(prefix="suggestion")
        globalmessageform = GlobalMessageForm(prefix="globalmessage")

    return render(request,'dashboard/test_page.html',{'contactform':contactform,'subscriptionform':subscriptionform,'suggestionform':suggestionform,'globalmessageform':globalmessageform})
```

How to write html code to show and save these forms on test_page.html.I know how to show one form but there are 4 forms in this case.

I have coded like this but i cannot see any output on test_page.html. Page is completely blank.

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
{% load static %}  
<div>
<div>
 <form method="post" > 
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ contactform.as_p }}
 </form>
 </div>

 <div>
 <form method="post" > 
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ subscriptionform.as_p }}
 </form>
 </div>

<div>
<form method="post" > 
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ suggestionform.as_p }}
</form>
</div>

<div>
<form method="post" > 
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ globalmessageform.as_p }}
</form>
</div>

<input type="submit" name="Save">
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using multiple forms on a page in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5857363/using-multiple-forms-on-a-page-in-django)

Comment: I don't understand your question. Where does HTML come into this? You have four Django forms in your context, why can't you place them in your template?

Comment: Sir @DanielRoseman I have updated my question.May you please guide me now.

Comment: Well, this should work. Does base.html have a content block?

Comment: Well i forgot to close the div tag of content. Finally this solved my problem.Well anyways sir @DanielRoseman you are savior in any case.Thanks