# Django - NOT NULL constraint failed on stockinfo_note.stock_id - ForeignKey error

Tags: python, django

**Purpose and Problem:**

I want to put two forms in the same template and process them in the one view. I can get the template to display the two forms but not submit them (i.e process the submission). When I submit I get the following error:

```
Exception Value: NOT NULL constraint failed: stockinfo_note.stock_id
```

'stock' is the ForeignKey. I can't figure out how to get the function stock_new in Views.py to populate the foreign key ID which is what i think i need to do to overcome the above error.

**Models.py:**

```
class Stock(models.Model):
    '''
    Model representing the stock info.
    '''
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    ticker_code = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.ticker_code

class Note(models.Model):
    '''
    Model representing the note.
    '''
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    text_note = models.TextField()
    stock = models.ForeignKey(Stock)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text_note
```

**Forms.py**

```
class StockForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Stock
        fields = ('ticker_code',)

class NoteForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Note
        fields = ('text_note',)
```

**Views.py**

```
def stocknoter(request):
    stock = Stock.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    note = Note.objects.filter(user=request.user)

    context_dict = {'stock':stock, 'note':note}
    return render(request, "stocknoter/stock.html", context_dict)

def stock_new(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form1 = StockForm(request.POST)
        form2 = NoteForm(request.POST)
        if form1.is_valid() and form2.is_valid():
            stock = form1.save(commit=False)
            stock.user = request.user
            stock.save()

            note = form2.save(commit=False)
            note.user = request.user
            '''
            **THE PROBLEM IS AROUND HERE i think, how do i pass stock_id created 
            by form1 so form2 saves it as the foreignkey?**
            '''
            note.save()
            return redirect('stock')
    else:
        form1 = StockForm()
        form2 = NoteForm()
    return render(request, 'stocknoter/stock_edit.html', {'form1':form1, 'form2':form2})
```

As mentioned above, i think the problem lies with this latter section (sorry should add i am new to Django). What do i need to do to save the foreign key id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay solved the problem. In `stock_new` i added: `note.stock = stock`

So views.py now look likes this:

```
def stocknoter(request):
    stock = Stock.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    note = Note.objects.filter(user=request.user)

    context_dict = {'stock':stock, 'note':note}
    return render(request, "stocknoter/stock.html", context_dict)

def stock_new(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form1 = StockForm(request.POST)
        form2 = NoteForm(request.POST)
        if form1.is_valid() and form2.is_valid():
            stock = form1.save(commit=False)
            stock.user = request.user
            stock.save()

            note = form2.save(commit=False)
            note.user = request.user

            note.stock = stock

            note.save()
            return redirect('stock')
else:
    form1 = StockForm()
    form2 = NoteForm()
return render(request, 'stocknoter/stock_edit.html', {'form1':form1, 'form2':form2})
```

Comment: This helped answer the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/569468/django-multiple-models-in-one-template-using-forms