# Where put phone number filed

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

Some kind of user don't have phone number, some kind of user have. For example, shopping user have phone_numer, admin don't have.
So I add one ShoppingPorfile(OneToOne relation to user) for shopping user, because I don't want to let phone_numer's null=True.
But if do like this, I have to combine two form(UserForm + ProfileForm) to complete register:

```
if all(user_form, profile_form): 
    user = user_form.save()
    profile = profile_form.save(user=user)
```

Does it ok? or you have more better advice.

Comment: hope this answer help u https://stackoverflow.com/a/575133/6396981

Comment: the question maybe not how to handle mutiple form, but the  database design of the user is right?

Comment: I think it should be ok, coz you have `ForeignKey` field that reference to the user.