# Django Forms: Cannot get to data to save from ModelForm

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I am creating a job board site. Right now I can successfully register an Employer but when I try to create a job listing while logged in as an Employer, the data from the form does not save to the database. I have the following models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.http import HttpResponse


# Create your models here.
class Employer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.first_name


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_employer(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Employer.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_employer(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.employer.save()

class Job(models.Model):
    poster = models.ForeignKey(Employer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    job_title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    establishment_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    details = models.TextField(max_length = 2000)
    salary = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    address = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    state = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    zip_code = models.CharField(max_length = 10)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.job_title + " - " + self.establishment_name \
               + ", " + self.poster.user.first_name + " " +self.poster.user.last_name
```

A user can register as an employer just fine, but I am having problems getting `Job`s to save to the database. Once a user registers/logs in as an employer they are redirected to employer_home.html, where an employer can post a job:

```
{% extends 'core/base.html' %}


{% block body %}
    <h1>Post a Job</h1>

    <form>
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit">Post</button>


    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Here is my forms.py:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Job
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm


class EmployerSignupForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields =  ('first_name',
                   'last_name',
                   'email',
                   'username',
                   'password1',
                   'password2',)

class JobPostForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Job
        fields= ('job_title',
               'establishment_name',
               'salary',
               'address',
               'state',
               'zip_code',
               )
```

and here is my employer_view(view to handle `Job` form):

```
def employer_home(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = JobPostForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponse('Working!')
    else:
        form = JobPostForm()
    return render(request, 'core/employer_home.html', {'form': form})
```

employer_home.html displays a form with no problem, but when the form is submitted none of the data is saved to the database and the `return HttpResponse('Working!')` is never executed, it simply reloads the empty form. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add method="POST" in your form. In your view do this:

```
def employer_home(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = JobPostForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        job_object = form.save(commit=False)
        job_object.poster = poster_object
        job_object.save()
        return HttpResponse('Working!')
else:
    form = JobPostForm()
return render(request, 'core/employer_home.html', {'form': form})
```

A good example is shown here: [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/569468/django-multiple-models-in-one-template-using-forms/575133#575133)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but where is the poster_object coming from?

Comment: I think this is the issue which is causing the error. In your "Job" model you have a field "poster " which is a Fkey. So when saving, the form the expects a poster object since it is not set as null=True or blank=True. So in your view you are missing a query to fetch the corresponding poster object. The model does not get saved on calling form.save(commit-=False). The object get only saved when the save is called.

Comment: Nevermind, I figured out the poster_object part, thanks for your answer it is working!

Comment: Hope it helped. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try `<form method="post">` in your html template.
By default, the method is *get*.

Comment: I always seem to think the problem is in the wrong file,  I was sure there was something wrong with my views.py. Thanks, @aquaman ill accept your answer when I am allowed to.

Comment: do you know how I would set the `poster` value @aquaman, as the form is now submitting properly but I am getting the error: "NOT NULL constraint failed: core_job.poster_id"?